# Multiple arguments composible function implementation using reduceRight()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to re-implement function composition using `reduceRight`. Here is a function composition that I am trying to re-implement:

```
const compose = function([func1, func2, func3]) {
  return function(value1, value2) {
    return func1(func2(func3(value1, value2)));
  };
};

const func3 = (x, y) => {
  return y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3;
};

const func2 = x => {
  return x ** 2;
};

const func1 = x => {
  return x - 8;
};

const fn = compose([func1, func2, func3]);

console.log(fn('3', 1)); // 1081
console.log(fn('3', -1)); // -8
```

The following code is re-implementation of the above function. It looks like the argument `y` is getting `undefined` I am not sure why.

```
const compose = (...args) => value =>
  args.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), value);

const func3 = (x, y) => {
  return y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3;
};

const func2 = x => {
  return x ** 2;
};

const func1 = x => {
  return x - 8;
};

const fnOne = compose(
  func1,
  func2,
  func3
)('3', 1);
console.log(fnOne);//-8

const fnTwo = compose(
  func1,
  func2,
  func3
)('3', -1);
console.log(fnTwo);//-8
```

Comment: You just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55842013/10221765) (>10k).

Comment: `func3 ` expects 2 values

Comment: @JackBashford Yes I deleted it to try to find solution on my own. But I am having a hard time

Comment: @adiga I am not sure how to fix it

Comment: @JohnJohn If you don't care that `func3` will have only one argument it's easy to fix. Is that the case? Can `func3` live with one argument?

Comment: @Jenian this is what I am trying to fix. How to make it work with more then one argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to `compose`, you could use [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) syntax get an an array of `values`. Then [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `func3` arguments to get `x` and `y` like this:

```js
const compose = (...args) => (...values) =>
  args.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), values);

// an array of values is passed here
// destructure to get the x and y values
const func3 = ([x, y]) => y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3;

const func2 = x => x ** 2;

const func1 = x =>  x - 8;

const fnOne = compose(
  func1,
  func2,
  func3
)('3', 1);
console.log(fnOne);//1081

const fnTwo = compose(
  func1,
  func2,
  func3
)('3', -1);
console.log(fnTwo);//-8
```