# Function composition with multiple arguments using reduceRight() - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement function composition with multiple arguments using reduceRight. This question has been answered at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842990/multiple-arguments-composible-function-implementation-using-reduceright) but slightly with a different input data. For some reason I am getting the following error : `Uncaught TypeError: fn is not a function`. Avoid using `func3 = ([x, y]) => (y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3);` in this format. Let me know if there is a way to fix it.

```
 const compose = (...fns) => (...args) =>
      fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), args);

    const func3 = (x, y) => (y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3);
  //const func3 = ([x, y]) => (y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3); - avoid using this version

    const func2 = x => x ** 2;

    const func1 = x => x - 8;

    const fnOne = compose([func1, func2, func3])('3', 1);
    console.log(fnOne); // should be 1081

    const fnTwo = compose([func1, func2, func3])('3', -1);
    console.log(fnTwo); //should be -8


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842990/multiple-arguments-composible-function-implementation-using-reduceright
```

**SOLUTION**

Array#reduceRight only has support for one currentValue so we can't have a function accept multiple arguments. The only way would be to avoid using reduceRight for the first call by popping it from the array and calling it manual instead of letting reduceRight do it:

*First approach*

```
const compose = fns => (...args) =>
      fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), fns.pop()(...args));
```

*Second approach*

```
const compose = fns => (...args) =>
      fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(...[acc, ...args.slice(1)]), args[0]);
```

Comment: The "second approach" passes all parameters accept the first to all functions in `fns`, not only to the first. For example imagine `func1 = (x, y = 8) => x - y`. In this scenario you only expect the first argument given when in the middle of the chain. Your second approach will pass `1` for `fnOne` and `-1` for `fnTwo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing an array into compose instead of a function (or multiple functions), so `fn` is an array and you get that error when you try to use it as a function.

Either replace `...fns` with `fns` (so that compose expects an array) or remove the square brackets in your calls to compose. Also use the version of func3 that you have commented out:

```js
const compose = (...fns) => (...args) =>
      fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), args);

const func3 = ([x, y]) => (y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3);

const func2 = x => x ** 2;

const func1 = x => x - 8;

const fnOne = compose(func1, func2, func3)('3', 1);
console.log(fnOne); // should be 1081

const fnTwo = compose(func1, func2, func3)('3', -1);
console.log(fnTwo); //should be -8
```

Comment: I want to avoid using this version `const func3 = ([x, y]) => (y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3);`

Comment: @JohnJohn Array#reduceRight only has support for one `currentValue` so you can't have a function accept multiple arguments like that. The only way would be to avoid using reduceRight for the first call by popping it from the array and calling it manual instead of letting reduceRight do it: `const compose = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), fns.pop( )(...args));`

Comment: I see . Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @JohnJohn No problem

Comment: @Paul You can use `reduceRight` even for multiple arguments, you just have to spread them out when call `fn`. Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60725687/3982562).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't can or want to convert `func3` to a single argument function. You could spread the `args` when calling `fn`. Then capture the result in an array so it can be spread over the next `fn` call. When returning the final result simply take the first element of the resulting array.

```js
const compose = (...fns) => (...args) =>
  fns.reduceRight((args, fn) => [fn(...args)], args)[0];

const func3 = (x, y) => (y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3);
// const func3 = ([x, y]) => (y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3); - avoid using this version

const func2 = x => x ** 2;
const func1 = x => x - 8;

const fnOne = compose(func1, func2, func3)('3', 1);
console.log(fnOne); // should be 1081

const fnTwo = compose(func1, func2, func3)('3', -1);
console.log(fnTwo); //should be -8
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need provide to compose function three parameters/function instead a array.
2. func3 will be the first function performed, so it will receive the array args. This array need be [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in x and y variable. This reduce can be make in the parameters definition, like this: ([x, y]).

```js
const compose = (...fns) => (...args) =>
fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), args);

const func3 = ([x, y]) => y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3;

const func2 = x => x ** 2;

const func1 = x => x - 8;

const fnOne = compose(func1, func2, func3)('3', 1);
console.log(fnOne); // should be 1081

const fnTwo = compose(func1, func2, func3)('3', -1);
console.log(fnTwo); //should be -8
```